# Android AdMob banner ad not showing up

Tags: android, admob

I am using the following view in my activity xml.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6844894412719021~8904567900">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your code is correct or not, but one thing that I found out was that it took at least a minute for my own ad to load. Try waiting a bit longer and see if you find anything

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more information. What you have given is not enough to tell what the problem is. If you are unsure what to provide, first follow all of the instructions for setting up your app with AdMob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `adUnitId` seems to be incorrect. Did you get it via email?
You should be using following app id (replace ~ with /)

```
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6844894412719021/8904567900">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your xml:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

and to gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
```

Comment: How do you know that the OP doesn't already have this? They have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using app_id instead of banner_id.

```
<string name="app_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx</string>
<string name="banner_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

these two values are different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have latest versions of adMob and GooglePlayServices lib.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to show banner inside of svg images then care about it are you using smart banner or banner it may effect, sometimes you implement the code right but when you try to show toast in ad loaded like this.

```
 adView2.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                Toast.makeText(App_Mainpage.this, "add is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {


            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {


            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

            }
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView2.loadAd(adRequest);
```

if it shows you in toast the ad is loaded but not showing when you testing, then actually you are implementing Smart_banner that takes large space to show, so use Banner Just it will show then, i solve it by change this thing.

[image]

then i changed to smart banner .
[image]